# Why is margin: auto not being calculated correctly here

Tags: css

I am working on this site:  https://dev.notevenpast.org/brian-levack-possession-and-exorcism/

In this page I am attempting to center an image within a div with an id of monthly-feature-banner.  Here are the stylings for the banner and the image:

```
#monthly-feature-banner {
    width: 100%;
}
#monthly-feature-banner img {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Oddly, though, in both Chrome and FF the image margins are not equal.

Question:  Why is this happening?
Question:  What can I do to fix it?

EDIT:  The answer below suggesting `text-align: center;` had the same issue as `margin: 0 auto;` It should work, but it doesn't.  Also, the box-sizing fix helps if I remove it from the entire page, but it has side effects that make it impractical.
A comment below from @Alohi correctly pointed out that adding `clear: left;` to the containing div along with the `margin: 0 auto;` has the desired effect.  I will accept the first answer that contains that information.

Comment: The issue is the border-box layout... still trying to figure out why though.

Comment: Removing font-size or line-height on the body element seems to solve the problem, maybe that points to some kind of floating issue. Maybe not cleared properly?

Comment: @MattK. Indeed. `#monthly-feature-banner { clear: left; }` resolves the issue.

Comment: @Alohci You're correct.  The combination of your answer and answer works.  #monthly-feature-banner {text-align:center;clear:left;}  If you post that as an answer I will accept it (unless Marcel modifies his correctly first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `#monthly-feature-banner img` and add `text-align: center` to `#monthly-feature-banner`

Unless you intend to modify `#monthly-feature-banner` to something else the width will already be 100%, so `width: 100%;` or any `display:block;` styles you have are useless, a div itself is a block.

In short:

```
#monthly-feature-banner {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gs6rG/

If the image continues to be pushed to the right you could try adding `clear: left;`, which disallows floating elements on the left.

Comment: While that answer would, typically, work.  It does not work in  my case.  There is still some sort of strange issue where neither that nor margin: 0 auto; are behaving as expected.  However, when I cleared the #monthly-feature-banner and combined it with your answer it did work.  If you modify your answer to add "clear: left;" I'll accept it.

Comment: @vlasits I added it and it makes sense, but I can't seem to re-create the issue; added all styles to: http://jsfiddle.net/Gs6rG/1/

Comment: I'm not surprised you can't recreate it.  I feel like it's pretty edge casey.  I also feel pretty confident that it has something to do with the div that immediately precedes the #monthly-feature-banner div.  That one has some positioning defined on it.  I tried to recreate it by adding that div in:  http://jsfiddle.net/Gs6rG/2/ But I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#monthly-feature-banner {

    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

Comment: Should work, but it doesn't.  Adding clear: left to that div was required.